# Drawing Pixels in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

how would I manage pixel-by-pixel rendering in WPF (like, say, for a raytracer)? My initial guess was to create a BitmapImage, modify the buffer, and display that in an Image control, but I couldn't figure out how to create one (the create method requires a block of unmanaged memory)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I highly recommend *against* the previous two suggestions. [The WriteableBitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(VS.85).aspx) provides what you need assuming you are using 3.5 SP1. Before SP1 there's no really good answer to this question in WPF unless you resort to some serious trickery.

Comment: The WriteableBitmap class is available since .NET 3.0 and this is the first version of WPF. You don't need .NET 3.5 to use this class.

Answer (score 12):

If you are thinking of doing something like a ray tracer where you will need to be plotting lots of points you will probably want to draw in the bitmap's memory space directly instead of through the layers of abstraction.  This code will give you significantly better render times, but it comes at the cost of needing "unsafe" code, which may or may not be an option for you.

```
            unsafe
            {
                System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 240);
                IntPtr hBmp;
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480);
                Rectangle lockRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480);
                BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(lockRegion, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                byte* p;

                p = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (point.Y * data.Stride) + (point.X * 3);
                p[0] = 0; //B pixel
                p[1] = 255; //G pixel
                p[2] = 255; //R pixel

                bmp.UnlockBits(data);

                //Convert the bitmap to BitmapSource for use with WPF controls
                hBmp = bmp.GetHbitmap();
                Canvas.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbmpCanvas, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                Canvas.Source.Freeze();
                DeleteObject(hBmp); //Clean up original bitmap
            }
```

To clean up the hBitmap you will need to declare this near the top of your class file:

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Also note that you will need to set the project properties to allow unsafe code.  You can do this by right clicking on the project in solution explorer and selecting properties.  Goto the Build tab.  Check the "Allow unsafe code" box.  Also I believe you will need to add a reference to System.Drawing.

Comment: many errors.  BitmapData could not be found, ImageLockMode does not exist, PixelFormat does not contain a definition for Format24bppRgb, Canvas does not contain a definition for Source

Answer (score 8):

You can add small rects if you want, but each of those is a FrameworkElement, so it's probably a bit heavyweight. The other option is to create yourself a DrawingVisual, draw on it, render it then stick it in an image:

```
private void DrawRubbish()
{
    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(rand.NextDouble() * 200, rand.NextDouble() * 200, 1, 1));

        dc.Close();
    }
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    rtb.Render(dv);
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = rtb;
    MainGrid.Children.Add(img);
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Worked like a charm. Just one small thing:
dc.Close(); 
is not needed. Using calls Dispose(), which is doing the same like Close(). I checked WPF source code:-)

Answer (score 7):

you could place 1X1 Rectangle objects onto a Canvas

```
  private void AddPixel(double x, double y)
  {
     Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
     Canvas.SetTop(rec, y);
     Canvas.SetLeft(rec, x);
     rec.Width = 1;
     rec.Height = 1;
     rec.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
     myCanvas.Children.Add(rec);
  }
```

That should be pretty close to what you want

Comment: Using Rectangle to draw a pixel generates a huge overhead, because Rectangle inherits from Shape, which also defines 9 properties for drawing a border (Stroke) around the Rectangle and other not needed functionality. The pixel will be defined by a Geometry, which has its own overhead. But worst of all, Rectangle also inherits from FrameworkElement, which adds over 100 (!) properties supporting layouting, mouse and keyboard interactions, ContextMenu, ToolTip and much more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using WritableBitmap.

```
public void DrawRectangle(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap, int left, int top, int width, int height, Color color)
{
    // Compute the pixel's color
    int colorData = color.R << 16; // R
    colorData |= color.G << 8; // G
    colorData |= color.B << 0; // B
    int bpp = writeableBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;

    unsafe
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Get a pointer to the back buffer
            int pBackBuffer = (int)writeableBitmap.BackBuffer;

            // Find the address of the pixel to draw
            pBackBuffer += (top + y) * writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride;
            pBackBuffer += left * bpp;

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // Assign the color data to the pixel
                *((int*)pBackBuffer) = colorData;

                // Increment the address of the pixel to draw
                pBackBuffer += bpp;
            }
        }
    }

    writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(left, top, width, height));
}
```

And to use it:

```
private WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1100, 1100, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int size = 10;

    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    bitmap.Lock(); // Lock() and Unlock() could be moved to the DrawRectangle() method. Just do some performance tests.

    for (int y = 0; y < 99; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 99; x++)
        {
            byte colR = (byte)rnd.Next(256);
            byte colG = (byte)rnd.Next(256);
            byte colB = (byte)rnd.Next(256);

            DrawRectangle(bitmap, (size + 1) * x, (size + 1) * y, size, size, Color.FromRgb(colR, colG, colB));
        }
    }

    bitmap.Unlock(); // Lock() and Unlock() could be moved to the DrawRectangle() method. Just do some performance tests.

  image.Source = bitmap; // This should be done only once
}
```

Comment: note: don't include system.drawing, else it wont like the 'Color.RGB' call

Comment: I get an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll  :(

Comment: To support 64-bit you must replace `int pBackBuffer = (int)writeableBitmap.BackBuffer;` by `var pBackBuffer = writeableBitmap.BackBuffer`. Also you can remove the requirement for `unsafe` by replacing `*((int*)pBackBuffer) = colorData;` by `Marshal.WriteInt32(pBackBuffer, colorData)`