# Fast pixel drawing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, raytracing

I would like to write a simple ray tracer using WPF. It is a learning project and thus I favour configurability over performance (otherwise I'd go for C++).

I still want relatively fast pixel drawing. A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443867/drawing-pixels-in-wpf) on StackOverflow contains code to achieve this in WPF, by obtaining a GDI bitmap. From the relatively little I know about Windows programming,

1. GDI is slow
2. DirectX is fast
3. WPF uses DirectX underneath (not sure which parts of WPF though)

Is it possible to obtain pixel-level access using DirectX (not GDI) through the WPF Canvas (or similar)?

I will also consider suggestions for incorporating DirectX API calls within a WPF window (alongside other WPF controls) if that is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplest would be to create a command line application that renders something simple like a tetrahedron and save it to a png. Once you have that you would have solved a lot of problems related to the raytracer itself. Then you can worry about drawing to the screen etc.

Comment: @Gigi: I don't think it's wise to attempt to write directly to the screen in WPF - see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx

Comment: I think using a `WritableBitmap` could be a good idea.

Comment: @Surfbutler - that relates to using GDI, which the Gigi has already ruled out

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: I stand by the article I previously linked to - it indicates direct writes to the primary (screen) aren't allowed, and would be slow anyway (see the last section 'Drawing To and Reading From the Screen'

Comment: @Surfbutler I think the article you linked to is talking about something different - i.e. directly writing to video memory as opposed to writing to a window (or component thereof), which is what I want to do. Besides, the author is warning against something GDI-specific.

Comment: @Gigi: ok fair enough, just didn't want you running into problems - I also vote for WritableBitmap!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting, but with raytracing, writing the pixels to the screen will (should) not be the slow part.  You can use `WriteableBitmap` for the purpose, though.  It's certainly quick enough for what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

(For info, I use it in this emu/IDE - http://0x10c-devkit.com/ - and it can refresh a low res display with great performance.  There's the source to that on the github repository, the LEM1802 plugin.)

Ah, this bit: https://github.com/kierenj/0x10c-DevKit/blob/master/PluginAPI/NyaElektriska.LEM1802/GPU.cs - see `UpdateDisplay`.

Comment: You raise a valid point. I will do some research based on the links provided, and probably go with this.

Comment: Just to go along with the answer, I found this link helpful when attempting my implementation: http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/WpfPixelDrawing.html

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/reneschulte/WriteableBitmapEx). It extends the builtin WriteableBitmap.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open Source Project Called Direct Canvas wich is A hardware accelerated, 2D drawing API that supports vector graphics, multimedia files, extensible pixel shaders, blending modes and more!

http://directcanvas.codeplex.com/

Demo http://www.youtube.com/user/jdollah69#p/u

Comment: Unless the raytracing is done in a pixel shader, that's no use, and there will definitely be no use for vector graphics, multimedia files or blending modes.  Dude wants to write pixels, that's all