# How do I draw a pixel at a specific position on a window?

Tags: c#

I need to create a program that will display lines or dots of coordinates read from a txt file. The application will be attached to the output of an eye-tracking program, and will display the data.

How do I display some sort of graphic at a particular coordinate on the screen?

Note: The window is full-screen, and I can use WPF or WinForms.

Comment: Don't ask for off-site resources; thats just as bad. If this is WinForms or WPF the answer is actually pretty trivial; what are you using?

Comment: I could use either. I'm not sure which would be more appropriate.

Comment: Will this be a full screen window; so we can assume we can just put it on the correct coordinate in the window? I've got an answer if so.

Comment: Yep, the video is full screen. I mentioned below maybe using a transparent layered window. What do you think?

Comment: Please review my edit; I tried to combine all that information into the question and remove the fluff.

Comment: Yep, If I can display the coordinates on a transparent full screen window over the video being played back it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would overlay your video with an `Image` element; something like:

```
<Grid>
   <Image x:Name=TrackingImage />
   <MediaElement/>
</Grid>
```

Then in your code behind; set the source to a [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(VS.85).aspx). The documentation has an excellent sample, but to summarize it here:

```
WriteableBitmap writeableSource = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

// Calculate the number of bytes per pixel. 
int _bytesPerPixel = (writeableSource .Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
// Stride is bytes per pixel times the number of pixels.
// Stride is the byte width of a single rectangle row.
int _stride = writeableSource .PixelWidth * _bytesPerPixel;

private void SomeUpdateFunction()
{
     // Define the rectangle of the writeable image we will modify. 
     // The size is that of the writeable bitmap.
     Int32Rect _rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, _wb.PixelWidth, _wb.PixelHeight);

    //Update writeable bitmap with the colorArray to the image.
    _wb.WritePixels(_rect, pixelBuffer, _stride, 0);
    TrackingImage.Source = writeableSource;
}
```

Note that it uses `WritePixels` (specifically; this overload: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816(v=vs.110).aspx))

Obviously you will need to modify the parameters to get the correct pixel in the correct place. This is the right technique though.

This answer was inspired by: [Drawing Pixels in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443867/drawing-pixels-in-wpf) It might be worth looking at if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Various bitmap formats are instructions to put colored dots at specific locations.  Why not use something like that?  What ELSE do you need it to do?

Regarding your eye-tracking and point-data comment, if you want to composite it with captured video, then you don't need to worry about how to display the images so much as you need to think about how to add the dots to the video itself.  The video player will do the displaying.

From what I know about screen-capture and video codecs (not a whole lot) it will be best to work with the uncompressed video before it gets encoded.  Otherwise you'll have to decode, add, and re-encode.  I'd look for a way to hook into the capture program and add the live eye-tracker data to the captured frames.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Why not comment?

Comment: I just need to draw out the path made by the coordinates from data I collected with an eye tracker and display it over a video of the user using a program while we took in the data.

Comment: Other than the request for a "txt file" based format, which I think is probably erroneous, this is an answer, guidance.

Comment: I can easily read through the data and take the coordinates, I just need to know how to display them. I assume I'd start with a WPF in visual.

Comment: How are you doing the eye-tracking, by the way?

Comment: @uosɐſ But none of it (other than saying "use a bitmap") is even remotely related to the actual question. Guidance; yes, but I don't see an answer to "How do I put a pixel/graphic at a specific position on the screen" anywhere here.

Comment: With a camera and eyetracking software.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - That's not what I figured that he needs.  Other participants can attempt to answer the question more literally.

Comment: Simply put, if you could help me display a colored pixel at a certain coordinate I could take it from there. That would be a perfect answer.

Comment: well, I think that's also complicated, being able to superimpose time-synchronized images over a video player with appropriate scale.  I don't have any good ideas for that path.  If you solve that, you might implement a new window with a matching size to the video player and a transparent background, then you can use System.Drawing namespace, perhaps, to draw pixels to your window.

Comment: But video players work directly with the video card I think and don't draw the data to the screen as pixels the same way you would do it, so I don't know if compositing your transparent window and their video would work well.  Maybe it would.

Comment: What about a transparent layered window? The size of the video is that of the full screen.

Comment: If you're also hosting the video player than you might "layer" it, but I don't know what a "layered window" is besides that and besides what I was writing about just above.