# WPF - Create and draw image on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

I have WPF canvas. And I need to draw up to half million  pixels with different color. I've tried to draw pixel-by-pixel, but it was incredibly slow. So I've decided to create Image and draw it. I don't know, if it's the best way how to do it, so if you know better way, tell me.

So my question is, how can I create and draw image to canvas? I've searched, but I wasn't able to find anything.

I have two dimensional array of colors and I need to draw them, probably via an image, so how can I do it?

Thanks, Soptik

EDIT: Now, I use this code, but it takes seconds to draw even 100*100 pixels.

```
for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
   {
        Draw(i, j, Brushes.Aqua);
   }
```

...

```
private void Draw(int x, int y, SolidColorBrush b)
    {
        Line l = new Line();
        l.Stroke = b;
        l.X1 = x;
        l.Y1 = y;
        l.X2 = x + 1;
        l.Y2 = y + 1;
        l.StrokeThickness = 1;
        canvas.Children.Add(l);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to follow what code you might have now (we really need to see some code) you should try to draw more than one pixel at a time.

Comment: I've tried this: 

`
for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    Draw(i, j, Brushes.Aqua);
                }
            }
` where w is width and h is height, I just try to draw lines (i wasn't able to find, how to draw it better, so I draw lines) and it takes seconds to draw it.

Comment: Try adding that to your question text, makes it easier to read :)

Comment: It's there... But i would prefer to do it another way, this doesn't seem very good... But if you have any idea, tell me

Comment: What you're doing isn't bad, it's pretty normal to draw an image that way.  So, you're saying it is taking too long to draw the entire thing, or you'd like to see progress as it draws?

Comment: I dont thing, I need this... It was just surprisingly slow at my PC, so I thought, I was doing it bad. But if it's the best way to do it, thanks for your time :-) If you want, you may put an answer there, so I can mark this as answered.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/445064/5246145). I don't have enough experience in graphics to give you more info, but from first glance what you are doing isn't the way it should be done.

Comment: @3615 it is not that it's "bad" but there are certainly other ways to tackle the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current method is not "bad."  It might be slow due to the massive size of the 2d array you have, but looping through two `for loops` is normal for this process.  Some potential solutions could be loading each row as a `rect` onto your `Canvas` to show the image being processed, but if that is not necessary than I would investigate how to handle the pixel data and possibly processing more than one at time.

[This Question is similar to yours and might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443867/drawing-pixels-in-wpf)